# How to send alert on SQL Shutdown due to Audit Failure

Tags: sql-server, audit, scheduled-tasks

Looking for a way to implement this STIG. What method should I use to monitor SQL Server, when it is shutdown due to "Shutdown on Audit Failure"?

[SQL Server must provide an immediate real-time alert to appropriate support staff of all audit failure events requiring real-time alerts.](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/ms_sql_server_2016_instance/2019-12-10/finding/V-79231)

I have found Event ID: **33219**

Parameters:

- Cannot store a password, so difficult to use "Windows Scheduled Task"
- On a domain, remember not able to store a password
- PowerShell script:

```
 $recipients = "<FirstRecipient@domain.tld>,<NextRecipient@domain.tld>"
 Send-MailMessage -To $recipients -Subject "SQL Audit Failure" -Body "SQL has shutdown due to Audit Failure." -SmtpServer NameOrIPAddress -From SQLEmail@domain.tld -Priority High
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User assigned to Task in Task Scheduler must be assigned the "User Rights Assignment" "Log on as a batch job"

1. Select the radio button: "Run whether user is logged on or not"
2. Check the box: "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources."
3. Click Ok.
4. Enter password for account to run the script.
5. Click Ok.

[image: In Task Properties under the "General Tab" in "Security Options Section"]